# How can I specify Standard SQL in a Talend tBigQueryInput query?

Tags: google-bigquery, talend

I have tried specifying standard SQL using a query prefix with this syntax but Bigquery seems to ignore the directive:

```
"#standardSQL  \r\n
select column1 from `mydataset.myview`"
```

but I get this error:

```
Running Query : #standardSQL  
select column1 from mydataset.myview
---> Reason: invalidQuery
Message: Cannot reference a SQL view in a Legacy SQL query.
```

Comment: It looks like Talend might be prepending their own `--` or `#` style comment to your query before it is sent to BigQuery. Does Talend provide some other way of specifying the SQL dialect? If not, it might be good to file some kind of feature request with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by removing the space between "#standardSQL and \r\n.

Works:

```
"#standardSQL\r\n
```

Doesn't work:

```
"#standardSQL \r\n
```

RTFM:

```
"Must be separated from the query by a newline character"
```

My update to the FM:

```
"Must be separated from the query by ONLY a newline character"
```